# Anaconda Nav wont launch 18.04

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I type in anaconda-navigator but i get this "anaconda-navigator: command not found"
I have conda update conda.

Answer (score 5):

Run this command on your terminal:

```
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
$ anaconda-navigator
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: It worked for me. But after restarting the system I have to run it again. How to save this behavior?

Comment: You may add these lines to $HOME/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and change your directory

```
cd ~/anaconda3/bin
```

Export the anaconda3 path

```
export PATH=/home/YourUsername/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Check whether your conda is working

```
conda --version
```

Launch the anaconda navigator

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Hope this helps!

**PS** It may take some time to launch navigator.

Answer (score 2):

First, check whether conda-navigator is installed in your system or not.

Use command

```
conda list anaconda
```

check whether anaconda-navigator is there or not. If not there then you have install anaconda-navigator

use command

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

Then use this command

```
anaconda-navigator
```

anaconda-navigator should launch